# In SonarQube, how reliable is the 'Sonar way' quality profile for security reviews?

Tags: java, security, sonarqube, static-analysis

Can I rely on this profile for also checking for well-known security issues (e.g., code injection, weak crypto, xss, etc., or should I rather use another default profile (or is there a 'recommended' profile that I can import?).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the "Sonar Way" quality profile is the starting point and should be treated as the baseline . Most teams are expected to learn and evolve and over a period of time should raise the BAR both in terms of security and quality requirements of code .

So to answer your question , it is OK to start with the Sonar Way with a plan and desire to move to Extend the quality profile to meet your teams / organization's code quality and code security objectives.

However important to point out that some of the security issues that you point out like Code Injection , XSS can be more suitably detected using DAST tools.

Comment: Thank you for these details. 
I fully agree with you about the XSS example, not the best one I chose.

Still, I think the question remains: how trustworthy is this "baseline"? Can I trust it to catch common vulnerabilities or can I only trust it to catch "obvious" vulnerable coding patterns?